# Wordpress redirect htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a problem with my htaccess file in wordpress. I want to redirect users who come to /wp-login.php?action=register to another registration form with role parameter. Like this /wp-login.php?action=register&role=patient. So i wanna hide first url from users. I wrote this line in my htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^wp-login.php?action=register$ /wp-login.php?action=register&role=patient [NC,L]
```

It's located here in my file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-login.php?action=register$ /wp-login.php?action=register&role=patient [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

And i have no effect with that. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to match for the query string in a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^action=register$
RewriteRule ^wp-login[.]php$ /wp-login.php?action=register&role=patient [R,NC,L]
```

**Edit:** corrected my answer

Comment: RewriteRule ^wp-login.php[?]action=register$ /wp-login.php?action=register&role=patient [NC,L] I insert this in the same line, but nothing changed... The same problem...

Comment: Thanks, i found that solution when read documentation, and saw information about QUERY_STRING :) Any way, thanks for help!

Comment: @numediaweb there could be differences in your case of the problem, you can always ask a new question here at StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Another problem and solution involves htaccess:
When you have your website at a host provider from which you obtain Wordpress installation, it can occur that your WP is not in the root directory, but in a directory called Wordpress-xxxx

For instance: your website address is : `http://website.com`

so your path is: `http:/website.com/wordpres-xxx/file xxx`
However, most providers use in the background a redirect so it seems to your visitor goes directly to `http://website.com`

For htaccess this is a problem. If you look in your WP directory you will find htaccess and a good change it has the right format. But, there is another htaccess on your root. Often you cannot change this one, because your provider blocks it for any modification for safety reasons.

That is why your visitors cannot find your pages on your website (404) because that htaccess file in your root, did not change.

You have to ask your provider to sync both htaccess files. the one in WP should be copied/ overwrite the one in your real root directory.

that would solve the problem

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing the problem and solution related to the use of `.htaccess` in WordPress installations. I understand the issue you're describing. It can indeed be a problem when your WordPress installation is located in a directory called "Wordpress-xxxx" instead of the root directory, and the provider uses a redirect to make it appear as if the website is directly accessible from the root.

I've encountered a similar problem on my website. In my case, the WordPress installation was also in a subdirectory, causing issues with the `.htaccess` configuration and resulting in 404 errors for certain pages. Unfortunately, modifying the `.htaccess` file in the root directory was restricted by the hosting provider for security reasons.

To resolve this problem, it is necessary to contact the hosting provider and request them to synchronize both `.htaccess` files. The `.htaccess` file in the WordPress directory should be copied or overwritten to the one in the root directory. This ensures that the correct rewrite rules and configurations are applied, allowing visitors to access the website and its pages without encountering 404 errors.

If you're experiencing a similar issue, I recommend reaching out to your hosting provider and explaining the situation to them. They should be able to assist you in synchronizing the `.htaccess` files and resolving the problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34468964)